# What was the name of the magical robot from Dr. Strange?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-identification, doctor-strange

When my father was a teenager in the 60’s, he and his friends loved Dr. Strange more than any other comics. Then one day, Dr. Strange was attacked by some kind of magically powered robot. Issue after issue, Strange would try everything to defeat the robot but every one of his spells bounced off the robot, and still it kept coming. Finally, the showdown came to an end, Strange was cornered with nothing else left to him- and the robot tripped over its own feet, fell down, and broke into pieces.

My father carried the outrage at this until the day he died, feeling betrayed by his favorite character. He refused to even see the new movie two years ago, still nursing his grudge.

I thought his memory of the scene might be inaccurate, and looked up the scene in question. I managed to find the comic, and sure enough on page 2 or 3, the robot tripped over its own feet and fell apart. Strange then goes on as if nothing happened.

I wanted to look up the comic again, but I don’t remember the name of the robot, and obviously my father isn’t around anymore to ask.

I am fairly certain the issue was from the 60’s, from my memory of the artwork. It would also fit with my father being a teenager or early 20’s still at that time. By the late 60’s he had dropped out of comics and turned onto other things, so to speak, so I think it’s no later than 1967-ish if that helps at all.

Comment: Lucius Dilby's Robot? http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix7/dilby-lucius-robot.jpg

Comment: Grutan (AKA The Hulk)? https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/b/b3/Grutan_%28Earth-616%29_Tomb_of_Darkness_Vol_1_22.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140829231222

Comment: “feeling betrayed by his favorite character” — out of interest, how come he felt betrayed?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I would guess because Strange effectively did _nothing_ to defeat him and the robot was defeated by chance (based on OP description). Some would see that as a writing cop out.

Comment: @Matt - Usually termed (ironicly in this case) [a Dues ex Machina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina#Modern_criticism)

Comment: @Matt Strange did *everything* to defeat the robot! It just didn’t work! And given [how hard it is to make robots walk like people](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/4wt5ph/eli5_why_cant_we_make_robots_that_walk_like_people/), arguably this was well-informed and prescient writing! (I realise I’m essentially trying to convince a man who has, sadly, passed away. I should probably stop.)

Comment: Indeed. I am judging the writing based on what I know today. Made some more sense at the time.

Answer (score 31):

Maybe Voltorr, also known as Voltorg?

In *Strange Tales* #165 (1968), Doctor Strange went against Yandroth, Scientist Supreme. They fight the good old way (read: lots of punching), and Strange has the upper hand, but the issue ends with the reveal of Yandroth's latest creation, the robot Voltorr. Voltorr's source of power is the "lightning of the universe", which can "obliterate human life".

To be honest, given that Yandroth is the "Scientist Supreme" I'm not sure if it's supposed to be some kind of magic, but then again, the idea that 60s comic books writers had of science was sometimes borderline magic.

[image: Voltorr]

The next issue has Strange trying out some spells against the robot (now named Voltorg), and he does manage to "blank out its scanner circuits", but in the meantime he also gets thrown around a lot, dodging blasts at the very last moment ([or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dto0.png)), and eventually realizes that the robot only has one weak point: his eyes. He proceeds to strike Voltorg right in the face.

[image: Dr Strange blinds Voltorg]

The now blind robot wanders around, trying to blast Strange, but eventually hits a wall, making one big hole in the process, falls down and breaks into pieces. Strange then goes away to try and catch Yandroth.

[image: Voltorg is destroyed]

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure that is the one, because even if "robot breaks after falling over" and timeframe are right, Strange did manage to hold his own against the thing, and wasn't really cornered when the robot tripped. Still worth mentioning this issue, though!

Comment: Is that Voltor**r** or Voltor**g**? Both name are use in those picture.

Comment: @DragandDrop First line of the answer "Maybe Voltorr, also known as Voltorg?"

Comment: @DragandDrop Everyone knows [the good guys don't pay much attention to the bad guy's name](https://youtu.be/tVYx4qcXciw?t=71)

Comment: _Are_ those lightning rods? Because it looks like he's about to bust out a wicked drum solo.

Comment: @indextwo they're referred to as [electrodes forming power arcs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkfoo.png) (but also [atomic bolts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbn45.png), because you know, science is _complicated_). But your comment reminded me of [this robot drummer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6N_5-6uw6rg) :p

Comment: @Jenayah I figured they were supposed to be electrodoodads, but that first pose is just _so hard rock_. Funnily enough, that image & your comment reminded me of [these metalheads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RBSkq-_St8) ^_^

Comment: @DragandDrop - I do note that the "G" doesn't seem to exactly fit with the rest of the letters. It could be a last-minute paste job, changing the second "R" to a "G" after the lettering was already done. It's possible that, right before the second issue went to press, they realized there was already some character named Voltorr, and they changed the name to avoid issues.

Comment: Hm. It has been many years since I saw the comic but I feel sure it showed him tripping over his own feet. Possibly a “last time on Dr. Strange” kind of thing? Bit of a reach, I know.

Comment: @Broklynite I've been through the 1968 _Doctor Strange_ solo series and found nothing so far (except that whatever the writers were on, it was strong). "Last time on Dr. Strange" splash page seems like it could be a thing, yeah! Well I haven't found more in the later issues either, but the scans I'm reading are from the reprinted comics - maybe they cut something out... the search continues :p

Comment: My theory is that its name is really Voltorg, but Yandroth simply pronounced it wrong.

Comment: I don't see how any robot would be any trouble for Dr. Strange if his hands can shoot *"firey beams of occult force"* that turn metal into *"white hot molten metal"*... maybe the earlier frames explain why only the face was vulnerable, because it looks like he could've turned the whole robot into *white hot molten metal robot stew*

Comment: I love the "ish" abbreviation!

Comment: I have read almost every single Dr. Strange story, and this is the only robot I remember him fighting.